# Does `ON CONFLICT` in postgres use db locks to ensure there aren't any duplicate rows in POSTGRES?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Does `ON CONFLICT  DO NOTHING` lock the table to ensure that we don't insert duplicate rows?

Can anyone share any notes on the internal working of `ON CONFLICT` on different cases?

Answer (score 1):

For first question from documentation [Insert ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

> INSERT with an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause is a “deterministic” statement. This means that the command will not be allowed to affect any single existing row more than once; a cardinality violation error will be raised when this situation arises. Rows proposed for insertion should not duplicate each other in terms of attributes constrained by an arbiter index or constraint.

As to second question the source [execIndexing.c](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/executor/execIndexing.c;h=1f1181b56044a599398433a0f7feb45206a28abd;hb=HEAD) is probably where you will find the answer. Look for comments with section header *Speculative insertion*.